# Tikz \subnode positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikzmark

I have a problem with `\subnode` positioning when coordinates are negative. The sample code below works well, if the third subnode is commented. Otherwise, all positions are broken. How can I prevent this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    % Draw grid
    \def\nlines{5}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,\nlines} \draw[thick](\x, 0) -- (\x, \nlines);
    \foreach \y in {0,...,\nlines} \draw[thick](0, \y) -- (\nlines, \y);

    \node at(2.5, 0.5) {\subnode{a0}{} A};
    \node at (a0.base) {A0};

    \node at(2.5, 1.5) {\subnode{b0}{} B};
    \node at (b0.base) {B0};

    \node at(2.5, -0.5) {\subnode{c0}{} C};%comment this line
    \node at (c0.base) {C0};% comment this line
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where you find definition of `\subnode`? What is purpose of it?

Comment: @Zarko It is defined by the `tikzmark` library.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., thank you for info. Unfortunately this library is not described in Tikz manual (I look in v3.0.1a). Where to find some description of it?

Comment: @Zarko No, it's a third party library. But it is on CTAN (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark?lang=en), so you may have it installed already, and then the documentation is found with `texdoc tikzmark`. Or you can find it at [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikzmark/tikzmark.pdf).

Comment: @TorbjørnT., I found it! Thank you for information. Now it is not clear (to me), what OP like to achieve with this library. For naming node as Harish Kumar say in his answer? Or like to later have some more fancy stuff? Well, this is questions for OP ...

Comment: Well, I put a simplified example. In reality, i have multiple subnodes in each node that serve as placeholders for subsequent plotting.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way to label a node. you should put a label like

```
\node (a0) at(2.5, 0.5)  {A};  %% (a0) is the label
```

and then

```
\node at (a0.base) {A0};
```

works.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw grid
    \def\nlines{5}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,\nlines} \draw[thick](\x, 0) -- (\x, \nlines);
    \foreach \y in {0,...,\nlines} \draw[thick](0, \y) -- (\nlines, \y);

    \node (a0) at(2.5, 0.5)  {A};
    \node at (a0.base) {A0};

    \node (b0) at(2.5, 1.5) {B};
    \node at (b0.base) {B0};

    \node (c0) at(2.5, -0.5) {C};%comment this line
    \node at (c0.base) {C0};% comment this line
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I put a simplified example. In reality, i have multiple subnodes in each node that serve as placeholders for subsequent plotting.

Comment: @BlazBratanic: Without knowing what are the subsequent plotting, it is hard to comment. Do you want to plot these subsequent plots out side this (particular) `tikzpicture` environment? If not, you shouldn't be using `\subnode` at all. I have the same questions as Zarko.

Answer (score 2):

When using `\subnode`, you need to have `remember picture` set on the surrounding picture.

A `\subnode` is effectively a new picture and TikZ works out where it is by comparing its absolute position on the page.  For this to work properly, TikZ also needs to know where the outer picture is, otherwise it can't work out the relative positions.  It falls back on some defaults which in this case mean that the relative position keeps growing with each compilation.

Also when fixing this then you'll need to delete the `aux` file to remove the old incorrect positions.

(The documentation currently doesn't state this - I'll fix that in the next release.)